# How to create a local database in Visual Studio 2015 Community?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-ce

I'm new to C# and SQL and I'm trying to add a `.sdf` file into my project in Visual Studio 2015, but I'm not finding it in the add file tab. I only find service-based database, but I want a local database, how do I do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read MSDN, get a manual, search how to. Your getting downvoted because it looks like you have done minimal research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.sdf` files are SQL Server **CE** (Compact Edition) files.

SQL Server CE is no longer being supported and developed by Microsoft, and doesn't have any tooling inside Visual Studio.

You can however [download and install SQL Server CE Toolbox](https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) which is a stand-alone tool, *and* also integrated into Visual Studio, for handling all things SQL Server CE.